# Чем плохи большие размеры исполняемых файлов?

Tags: c++, оптимизация, сборка, компоновщик

Уже не раз видел ответы людей по типу:

> [`-О3`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) генерирует быстрый, но раздутый исполняемый файл

> [*LTO*](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization) помогает этот раздутый код уменьшить

> Шаблоны *С++* приводят к распуханию исполняемого файла, это плохо

или

> Используй компоновщик [*gold*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA)) вместо [*gnu-ld*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_linker), он собирает меньший по размеру исполняемый файл...

Каждая из приведенных фраз это, конечно, целая дискуссия, но у всех одна цель - уменьшить размер бинарного файла.

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему так важно иметь как можно меньший по размеру бинарный файл? Связано ли это со скоростью загрузки приложения, кэша инструкций процессора, или еще с чем-то?

Comment: Связано со скоростью загрузки. Несколько раз попадались .exe файлы по несколько гигабайт, так они грузились от 10-ти минут до получасу.

Comment: А вам самим не противно, когда вы наделали бинарник метров на 100? Я помню времена, когда на 1 дискету влезала ОС, среды разработки и еще место для игрушек оставалось. А сейчас хелловорлд будет весить раз в 10 больше.

Comment: Это лучше спросить у тех, кто так утверждает. Как правило, им не найдётся, что сказать. Но причины могут быть и адекватные, тогда человек сможет объясниться (это редкое явление).

Comment: @ixSci: Проблема может быть, например, с «борьбой» за кеш процессора. При компактном коде вероятность того, что часто используемые куски объектного кода окажутся в кеше, больше.

Comment: @ixSci, не, ну если совсем бесмысленно уменьшать размер, то зачем тогда существует опция -Os?

Comment: @xperious, я не говорил, что всегда бессмысленно. Но чаще всего в этом нет необходимости. Собственно я опять повторил то, что сказал ранее, просто другими словами.

Answer (score 8):

Для начала предлагаю отвлечься от слова "исполняемый" и рассмотреть просто файл. Что значит большой размер? Файл потребует больше места для хранения, он дольше будет копироваться или как-то иначе обрабатываться, когда речь идет об обработке его содержимого, а не просто имени или даты создания. В таких случаях часто прибегают к механизмам дополнительного сжатия информации, проще говоря, архивированию. Это уменьшит размер и время копирования, но для последующей обработки, вероятнее всего, придется выполнить распаковку, что может в итоге даже увеличить время обработки по сравнению с несжатым файлом.

Теперь, чем отличается исполняемый файл от обычного? Он так или иначе содержит код, набор инструкций, которые должен выполнить (обработать) процессор. Понятно, что размер программы зависит от предоставляемого функционала, и наращивание логики приведет к увеличению размера. В большинстве случаев это не является проблемой, так как диски становятся всё больше, память и процессоры быстрее, а архитектурные решения опираются на декомпозицию: разделение кода на модули/библиотеки и подгрузку кода по мере необходимости. Но в некоторых ситуациях, например, в микроконтроллерах ресурсы серьезно ограничены и там идет борьба за размер, и использование разных техник оптимизации.

Кстати, для исполняемых файлов тоже существуют архиваторы, один из них, это [UPX](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPX).

Comment: хм, а есть связнь между кэшем-инструкций и размером бинарника?

Comment: @xperious как и с любым другим кэшем. Чем больше кэш и чем меньше данных для него - тем лучше.

Answer (score 2):

> -О3 генерирует быстрый, но раздутый исполняемый файл

По нынешним временам для большинства задач скорость более критична чем размер файла. Если код быстрый (все инлайн подстановки выполнены, многие циклы развернуты, все инварианты вынесены из циклов) то больше ничего от кода и не надо. Ребята, которые пишут оптимизаторы, не зря едят свои гамбургеры. Если нужен БЫСТРЫЙ код, то следует применять оптимизацию.

> шаблоны c++ приводят к распуханию исполняемого файла

Это утверждение более чем спорно. Если шаблоны нужны в данной задаче, то они никак не увеличивают код по сравнению с ручным переписыванием классов с незначительными изменениями. В любом случае инстанцирование шаблона в С++ вполне прозрачно и всегда понятно, во что компилятор развернет шаблон.

UPD1: Для микроконтроллеров теоретически есть проблема размера бинарника но и там память дешевле чем скорость даже более чем на десктопах и серверах. Так что если на микроконтроллере бинарник не влезает в память, то это показатель плохого дизайна системы. Всегда проще и дешевле поставить лишний чип памяти, а вот добавить лишних терафлопсов это уже совсем другие деньги.

Comment: С микроконтроллером не всегда проще поставить лишний чип памяти, например когда железо уже готово или запущено в производство, а требования как обычно в процессе растут. Иногда даже приходится использовать более специализированные компиляторы, когда GCC на максимальной оптимизации не дает нужного размера.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalyan Обычно, если разговор идет о том, что программа не лезет в память, то все равно систему (и железо и ПО) придется переделывать. По моему опыту, если в системе реального времени нет запаса и по памяти и по скорости хотя бы в два раза, то такую систему запустить не получится.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, `если разговор идет о том, что программа не лезет в память, то все равно систему (и железо и ПО) придется переделывать` -- или набрать других программеров.

Comment: @avp 11 Есть старый анекдот - если "предприятие" перестало приносить доход, то надо менять не мебель а девочек. Но с таким же успехом можно сказать что надо поменять тех орлов, которые запроектировали железо, не обеспечивающее нужной производительности. В моей практике я видел, например, как люди на ADSP пытались сделать роутер мотивируя это "но он же быстрый". :-)